# Segment greyscale image components color into black, white and grey

Tags: python, image

After a long time of trying this and that I still cannot find a proper solution to my problem. The problem is to segment this greyscale image into 3 different colors: the boudaries should be black, the internal space of the boudary should be white, and all the other medium should be black.

[image]

I tried several different methods including straightforwad intensity segmentation and some other morphological segmentation. But what I have got have two main problems:

- 1. There is always some grey pixels inside the black boundary which I cannot remove. (Main concern)
- 2. For those small objets, the detail is likely to be lost after segmentation.

Current result:

[image]

The expected ouput should have clear boudaries of three different colors, a least shouldn't have the grey lines inside the black boudary. I mean inside the black boudaries it shound be all white, without any grey. Sort of like this image I created, they don't have exact the same structure but please notice how clean it is, this kind of clean and exact sementation is what I want.

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: You'll need to explain what you need somewhat better.  The "expected output" you posted does not match up with the boundaries of the original image; I have no idea what sort of partitioning justification you have.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I just added some explanation. Please see if they would help you understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply some region-fill effects.  There are two that will do you a lot of good, especially because you're good at finding black boundaries.  Do as you've already done to determine those.  You will also need to replace any small (by your definition) black region with no interior, turning it grey (for now; might change).

1. Find the inner and outer hull of each region (known algorithms).  Everything inside gets turned white; everything outside gets turned grey.
2. Apply an "influence dithering" in all regions: replace each pixel with the mean of its immediate neighbors; a black pixel does not get involved.  Repeat the mean operation until each region settles near a white or grey value.  Then drive the entire region to that value.

.

Comment: Do you mean mode instead of mean?

Comment: No, but `mode` would also work well -- maybe even better.

Comment: I tried using the flood fill algorithm to fill whatever inside a closed shape into white. But it wasn't working perfectly. Not only inside the black boundary was flood filled but also some other places, which means more errors were added. Do you have any idea that I could control the size of the holes I am going to flood fill?

Comment: It's hard to recommend a repair when you haven't specified the problem.  "It wasn't working perfectly" and "also some other places" is not a problem specification.

Comment: So when we are looking for closed contours to use the flood fill algorithm, some other shapes like noise dots will be considered as closed shape to be filled as well. Whcih means we'll have a image like I posted below.